# How to point the createuserwizard and login tools to a remote sql server?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, authentication, createuserwizard

I have no idea how to point the createuserwizard and login tool to a remote sql-server. I'm building a website, which is based on ASP.net. Is there any code or web.config that I need to add to make it connected?

Thanks
Jimmy

Comment: Are you wanting to create a login for your app or for SQL Server? Or are you trying to connect to a database with an existing login?

Comment: Yes, I have been authorized to use the database and have the username and password of the database. The problem is I don't know how to link those two tool to the database. Because they have their own features and different from the normal textboxs